# Converting a string to an inputStream and then store in R.raw folder?

Tags: android

With following code I managed to convert a sound file stored in R.raw folder to string.

```
 InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bell_1);
    byte[] bell_sound = new byte[0];
    try {
        bell_sound = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String audioToString = new String(bell_sound);
```

How can I convert it back from string into whatever format and store as a new file named

```
R.raw.bell_2
```

in R.raw folder?

Comment: No, you can't write into the raw folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use raw during runtime. Ir's resources you can add only when you originally develop the app.  What you can do is store in external storage or internal. Either way you'll have to declare those permissions in android manifest file as following

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Resources are read-only at runtime. You cannot create new raw resources from Java code in the app. You are welcome to save it as a file in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), though.

Comment: Okay. Thankyou for the information. How can I play a sound from a string then?

Comment: hey, thanks.     MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
mp.start();

Comment: @hyperCoder: "How can I play a sound from a string then?" -- um, you can't. I do not know what you are attempting to accomplish via the code in your question. I also would not expect your code in the question to be reliable, as you assume that `available()` is going to return the full number of bytes in that resource. [The documentation says otherwise](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available()).

Comment: in this what do i put as res id if audio file is stored on external storage

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I'm trying to convert a sound file into string and then the string back into soundFile. Do you know of any other method I can do that?

Comment: @hyperCoder: "I'm trying to convert a sound file into string and then the string back into soundFile" -- why? "in this what do i put as res id if audio file is stored on external storage" -- you don't. You use one of the `setDataSource()` methods on `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: I am trying to build a chat app. where you can send photos, audio files, videos. I have managed to send and store photos. I converted them to string and then back into photos. I assumed thats how I should go about sending sound files as well. That's why I'm trying this. Is there another way you can suggest. Just checked your profile btw. Awesome :)

Comment: @hyperCoder: Usually, when we send photos, audio files, [and] videos over the Internet, we do so in binary form, rather than converting them to strings. You are certainly welcome to convert a `byte[]` into a string if you want, though you should use a standard format (e.g., base64 encoding). To play it back, the simplest thing would be to decode back to binary, write that to a file, and play the file.